# urllib.request in Python 2.7

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I can use urllib.request module with Python 3.1. But when I execute the same program using Python 2.7, an error comes along the lines of;

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'.
```

I believe this error is because theres no request module in urllib for Python 2.7. Because I need to use [tweepy](http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy) i'll have to stick with Python 2.7 since tweepy does not support Python 3.

So how I can use urllib.request module in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`urllib2.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) for Python 2.

Answer (score 37):

It is also possible to use `six` module to make code for both python2 & python3:

```
from six.moves import urllib
# ...
result = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Comment: This should be the top comment.

Comment: This should be the top comment

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html.

The `urllib2` module is the predecessor to `urllib.request`/`urllib.error` (it has been split into those modules in Python 3.0).