# urllib.request module fails to install in my system

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, urllib, sudo

Tried installing urllib.request module using below command

```
sudo pip install urllib.request
```

but it returned

```
Downloading/unpacking urllib.request
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement urllib.request
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for urllib.request
Storing debug log for failure in /home/mounarajan/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I install this module?

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, but why don't you just install `urllib` -- i.e., `sudo pip install urllib`.  does that not include `request`?

Comment: it also throws same error

Comment: i'm just throwing darts at the wall here, but what about `sudo pip install urllib3`?  would that get you what you want?

Comment: or perhaps you need to install a version of `pip` compatible with python 3?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

urllib.request is only available in python3 branch.  See the following post for more info.  [urllib.request in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745771/urllib-request-in-python-2-7)

Comment: yeah i using python 3

Comment: what do you mean, "python3 filename.py"?  what is "filename.py"?

Comment: python3 is verson name and filename is the name of the file in which u save you program in your directory so python3 filename.py

Answer (score 8):

In python3 you must use urllib3 module.

```
$ pip3 install urllib3
```

Or if you're using a virtual env:

```
$ pip install urllib3
```

Answer (score 6):

In python 2 ,you simply use urllib
for example

```
import urllib
htmlfile=urllib.urlopen("your url")
htmltext=htmlfile.read()
```

in python 3,you need to use urllib.request

```
import urllib.request
htmlfile=urllib.request.urlopen("your url")
htmltext=htmlfile.read()
```

Answer (score 3):

For Python3 in cmd,

```
pip install urllib3
```

Or if you're using a anaconda:

```
conda install urllib3
```

Hope, this will help you

Answer (score 0):

For future reader (which I believe most of them are python3 users), urllib is already available on Python3 simply `import urllib` to your code.