# I Cannot install Urllib Module all other modules can be installed easily but this gave me error

Tags: python, pip

I am using Version 3.9.0 and also 3.8.5 for some tests i am a begginer with 6 months experience. Anyone can pls help me Thank you in advance, And i saw this [urllib.request module fails to install in my system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382709/urllib-request-module-fails-to-install-in-my-system)
but then it kept going.

Comment: [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) is part of the Python Standard Library and is already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can use it without installing it. Can you please try this :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/").read()
print(html)
```

Comment: Thanks! But geeksforgeeks search said you need to install urllib sorry for inconvenience