# urllib does not have the request attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

It happend to me a few times the last week, urllib that acts up for some reason.

```
req = urllib.request.Request(oauth_uri)
req.add_header('User-Agent', "Python client")
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req, bytes_)
data = resp.read().decode("utf-8")
```

It works, then it says `req = urllib.request.Request(oauth_uri)
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'`and then it as sudden as it acts up, it works again.

Does anyone know how this happens and how to solve it? I need it to function reliable.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you could consider to use the requests library. Its very easy to use and I've never encountered any problems with it.

Comment: Did you import `urllib.request`? You need to use `import urllib.request`, not `import urllib`.

Comment: That did fix it, but still, why would it work sometimes, and other times crap it's pants?

Comment: That's strange. The only thing I can think of is that you're *sometimes* running it with Python 2, or that *sometimes* something is doing `import some_lib as urllib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a python 2/3 issue. Sure you're opening your script with python3?

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745771/urllib-request-in-python-2-7) related question.

**EDIT:**

I think Carpetsmoker figured it out. This works here:

```
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request("http://example.com")
req.add_header('User-Agent', "Python client")
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data = resp.read().decode("utf-8")
print(data)
```

I've no clue why it only works sometimes though. Maybe a subtle bug in your code? It seems extremely odd if python was to suddenly "forget" an attribute of an imported module.

Comment: In 3.5.1 to be exact. I do not even have 2 installed at the moment.